# 'javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created' for Tomcat Valve

Tags: java, tomcat, xerces, tomcat-valve

I have been working on constructing a custom SAML 2.0 based single-sign-on Apache Tomcat valve. During the initialization of this Tomcat valve, at certain server startup runs (does not occur frequently during every server startup) I had been experiencing the following exception in the Tomcat logs:

```
05-Feb-2016 00:35:08.643 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
 javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:311)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:267)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:120)
    at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool.initializePool(BasicParserPool.java:505)
    at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool.<init>(BasicParserPool.java:141)
    at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.<init>(XMLConfigurator.java:88)
    at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.<init>(XMLConfigurator.java:74)
    at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:220)
    at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:207)
    at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultBootstrap.java:100)
    at org.wso2.appserver.webapp.security.sso.saml.SAMLSSOUtils.doBootstrap(SAMLSSOUtils.java:175)
    at org.wso2.appserver.webapp.security.sso.saml.SAMLSSOUtils.<clinit>(SAMLSSOUtils.java:113)
    at org.wso2.appserver.webapp.security.sso.bean.LoggedInSession$SAML2SSO.readObject(LoggedInSession.java:189)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doReadObject(StandardSession.java:1629)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:308)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:289)
    ... 43 more

05-Feb-2016 00:35:08.650 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /home/chiranga/WSO2-Internship-Projects/wso2-products/product-as/distribution/target/application-server-6.0.0/webapps/bar-app.war has finished in 1,119 ms
05-Feb-2016 00:35:08.651 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /home/chiranga/WSO2-Internship-Projects/wso2-products/product-as/distribution/target/application-server-6.0.0/webapps/sample.war
05-Feb-2016 00:35:09.615 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
05-Feb-2016 00:35:09.625 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.wso2.appserver.webapp.security.sso.saml.SAMLSSOUtils
    at org.wso2.appserver.webapp.security.sso.bean.LoggedInSession$SAML2SSO.readObject(LoggedInSession.java:189)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doReadObject(StandardSession.java:1629)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I browsed through several forums which suggested the use of the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

As suggested this did solve the issue previously which was occurring frequently, but I have seen the above exception been thrown sometimes during server startup.

And I also have the above mentioned DocumentBuilderFactory.class within the Tomcat lib folder.

Am I missing something which I should be having in my code or is this a performance related issue? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: did you got any solution for this issue?

Comment: No unfortunately not, I debugged the code as well but I could not find the proper issue.

Comment: I am investigating an issue where this occurs with the OpenJRE but not with the Oracle JDK, for reasons I still do not understand.